# Setting up a Captive Portal for Android Reverse Tethering with Gnirehtet

Tags: android, portal, captiveportal

This is my first post here. I've got a working setup with Gnirehtet using rust for reverse tethering on my Android device. Now, I'm curious if it's possible to configure a captive portal that pops up on the Android screen when connected through USB.

I've successfully implemented a captive portal for a wireless access point before, leveraging dnsmasq, hostapd, and nginx. Wondering if there's a way to repurpose or integrate some of that infrastructure for this USB reverse tethering scenario.

I have tried running Gnirehtet with a custom DNS and using iptables to redirect port 80 traffic like I did in the for the wireless access point. This allows me to type the IP of the portal in a browser URL and it will load but I am wondering if there is a way to have it automatically pop-up like a regular captive portal?

Any tips or guidance would be great!